# How to implement "LIKE ANY" in BigQuery (standard SQL)?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use "like any" function. However, BigQuery doesnot recognize "ANY" operator. Is there any function which can replace "LIKE ANY" ?

Bigquery - Standard SQL

```
    SELECT
      date,
      CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS string)) ord_browsers,
      hits.appInfo.landingScreenName,
      channelgrouping,
      trafficSource.source,
      trafficSource.medium,
      CASE
        WHEN channelgrouping = 'seo_brand' THEN 'Branded'
        WHEN hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE '%/article%'
      OR hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE '%/p/%' THEN 'ADS'
        WHEN (hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE ANY ('%/damesmode/%',  '%/herenkleding/%',  '%/kinderkleding/%',  '%/sportkleding/%')) THEN 'Plist'
        ELSE 'rest'
      END Landing_page
    FROM
      `meta-geography-145406.81187684.ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits
    WHERE
      (_table_suffix BETWEEN '20190201'
        AND '20190207')
```

Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ANY at [12:47]

Comment: Some years later we finally got [like any](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators) also in BigQuery!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simpler query with the same problem:

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 'XXXX/herenkleding/XXX' x
)

SELECT x
FROM TABLE
WHERE x LIKE ANY ( 
  '%/damesmode/%'  '%/herenkleding/%',  '%/kinderkleding/%',  '%/sportkleding/%'
)

Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ANY at [2:6]
```

Alternative 1: Replace with a series of LIKE OR

```
SELECT x
FROM TABLE
WHERE (x LIKE '%/damesmode/%' 
OR x LIKE '%/herenkleding/%'
OR x LIKE '%/kinderkleding/%'
OR x LIKE'%/sportkleding/%')

XXXX/herenkleding/XXX
```

Alternative 2: Combine into one regular expression

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 'XXXX/herenkleding/XXX' x
)

SELECT x
FROM TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(x
  , '/(damesmode|herenkleding|kinderkleding|sportkleding)/')

XXXX/herenkleding/XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach. This will keep your original query intact, while implementing what you want:

```
 SELECT
      date,
      CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS string)) ord_browsers,
      hits.appInfo.landingScreenName,
      channelgrouping,
      trafficSource.source,
      trafficSource.medium,
      CASE
        WHEN channelgrouping = 'seo_brand' THEN 'Branded'
        WHEN hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE '%/article%'
      OR hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE '%/p/%' THEN 'ADS'
        WHEN (hits.appInfo.landingScreenName LIKE c) THEN 'Plist'
        ELSE 'rest'
      END Landing_page
    FROM
      `meta-geography-145406.81187684.ga_sessions_*`,
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits, UNNEST([
       '%/damesmode/%',
       '%/herenkleding/%',
       '%/kinderkleding/%',
       '%/sportkleding/%']) AS c
    WHERE
      (_table_suffix BETWEEN '20190201'
        AND '20190207')
```

Notice the array being unnested and each item is being compared in the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery now includes a quantified like operator.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator_quantified

Comment: cool. it would be helpful to include an example in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE,
  CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS STRING)) ord_browsers,
  hits.appInfo.landingScreenName,
  channelgrouping,
  trafficSource.source,
  trafficSource.medium,
  CASE
    WHEN channelgrouping = 'seo_brand' THEN 'Branded'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.appInfo.landingScreenName , '/(article|p)/') THEN 'ADS'
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hits.appInfo.landingScreenName , '/(damesmode|herenkleding|kinderkleding|sportkleding)/') THEN 'Plist'
    ELSE 'rest'
  END Landing_page
FROM `meta-geography-145406.81187684.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190207'
```