# Any and All SQL operator in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Does BigQuery support any and all operators in Standard SQL?

I am trying to find all users who are getting higher than minimum salary in a department and below query doesn't work. I keep getting  "Unexpected keyword ANY" Message

```
select ENAME_, JOB_ from `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
where SAL_ = ANY(
    select min(sal_) from `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
    group by DEPTNO_)
group by JOB_,ENAME_
```

Comment: In [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators) documentation you can find all the operators in Standard SQL, and both `ANY` and `ALL` are not in that list. However, I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645666/how-to-implement-like-any-in-bigquery-standard-sql) with a similar issue and there are 3 possible solutions for that situation: - Use a series of `LIKE OR`
- Combine everything into one regular expression
- Use `CASE` You can check examples using this solutions in the SO question previously linked.

Comment: Thanks Miguel - Its a shame Bigquery doesn't support these really useful operators. .I will try using like or or case and see if that helps me to get to what I was after.

Comment: As @Miguel mentioned it is not supported by BigQuery at the moment. If you want, you can create a Feature Request at Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685) so it maybe gets added in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IN. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  ENAME_,
  JOB_ 
FROM `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
WHERE 
sal_ IN (
       SELECT
           MIN(sal_) 
       FROM `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
       GROUP BY DEPTNO_
    )
GROUP BY JOB_,ENAME_
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous.

If you want to find all employees where their salary is greater than the minimum salary, that isn't the same thing as "do any users earn greater than min salary" (ANY) or "do ALL users earn greater than the min salary" (AND).

The answer to the latter is always "no" because in this case, the min salary is calculated from the users' salaries. At least 1 employee will have that min salary, so it is impossible that ALL employees earn more than the min salary. At least 1 will have that min salary, because that's how you know what the min salary value is.

If the question is "do any users earn greater than min salary" or "do ALL users earn greater than the min salary" then yes, there are functions to do that in BigQuery: `LOGICAL_AND()` and `LOGICAL_OR()`.

```
--calculate the min salary value per department
WITH dept_min_sal AS (
    select DEPTNO_, min(sal_) AS minsalary
    from `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
    group by DEPTNO_
)
--now work out if ANY users earn more than that min salary value
SELECT
    DEPTNO_, 
    LOGICAL_OR(a.sal > b.minsalary) AS some_earn_greater_than_minsal
FROM 
    `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1` AS a
INNER JOIN 
    dept_min_sal AS b
        ON a.DEPTNO_= b.DEPTNO_
GROUP BY DEPTNO_
```

This will return TRUE if at least 1 user in the department has a salary value of (what they earn) > (calculated minimum salary).

To show all users who earn more than the minimum salary, as requested, is far simpler, and does not require `ALL` or its BigQuery equivalents `LOGICAL_AND()` or `LOGICAL_OR()`.

```sql
WITH deptminsal AS (
    SELECT 
        DEPT_,
        MIN(sal_) as minsal 
    FROM `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1`
    GROUP BY DEPT_
)
SELECT 
    a.DEPT_,
    a.ENAME_
FROM 
    `tescomobile---bigquery.internal.testing1` AS a
INNER JOIN 
    deptminsal AS b
        ON a.DEPT_ = b.DEPT_
WHERE a.sal_ > b.minsal
```